# how to change the image in a listview when an audio is playing and stopping

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview, audio-player

I have a list view which has two text views one image view , i also have a play image aligned to the right of the list view.. i want to change the play image to playing when the audio is playing.. and also turn back to play when the audio is stopped..

i have created a `boolean` *isPlaying* to check and set it to true and false.. but nothing seems to happen..

please guide...

the following is my fragment class..

```
public class FamilyFragment extends Fragment {

static boolean isActive = true;

private int lastSelectedPosition = -1;

/** Handles playback of all the sound files */
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

/** Handles audio focus when playing a sound file */
private AudioManager mAudioManager;

private ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();

final WordAdapter adapter;


/**
 * This listener gets triggered whenever the audio focus changes
 * (i.e., we gain or lose audio focus because of another app or device).
 */
private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener mOnAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {


    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {

        if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT ||
                focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) {
            // The AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT case means that we've lost audio focus for a
            // short amount of time. The AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK case means that
            // our app is allowed to continue playing sound but at a lower volume. We'll treat
            // both cases the same way because our app is playing short sound files.

            // Pause playback and reset player to the start of the file. That way, we can
            // play the word from the beginning when we resume playback.
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
            // The AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN case means we have regained focus and can resume playback.
            mMediaPlayer.start();

        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
            // The AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS case means we've lost audio focus and
            // Stop playback and clean up resources

           releaseMediaPlayer();

        }
    }
};

/**
 * This listener gets triggered when the {@link MediaPlayer} has completed
 * playing the audio file.
 */
private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // Now that the sound file has finished playing, release the media player resources.

            if(lastSelectedPosition != -1){
            Word lastWord = words.get(lastSelectedPosition);
            lastWord.isPlaying = false;
            lastSelectedPosition = -1;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
            releaseMediaPlayer();

    }
};

public FamilyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  final  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list, container, false);

    // Create and setup the {@link AudioManager} to request audio focus
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    // Create a list of words

    words.add(new Word(R.string.family_father, R.string.miwok_family_father,
            R.drawable.family_father,R.string.miwok_family_father, R.raw.family_father));
    words.add(new Word(R.string.family_mother, R.string.miwok_family_mother,
            R.drawable.family_mother,R.string.miwok_family_mother, R.raw.family_mother));
    words.add(new Word(R.string.family_son, R.string.miwok_family_son,
            R.drawable.family_son, R.string.miwok_family_son, R.raw.family_son));
    words.add(new Word(R.string.family_daughter, R.string.miwok_family_daughter,
            R.drawable.family_daughter,R.string.miwok_family_daughter, R.raw.family_daughter));
    words.add(new Word(R.string.family_older_brother, R.string.miwok_family_older_brother,
            R.drawable.family_older_brother, R.string.miwok_family_older_brother, R.raw.family_older_brother));


    // Create an {@link WordAdapter}, whose data source is a list of {@link Word}s. The
    // adapter knows how to create list items for each item in the list.
     adapter = new WordAdapter(getActivity(), words, R.color.category_family);

    // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
    // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
    // word_list.xml layout file.
    final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);


    // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link WordAdapter} we created above, so that the
    // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link Word} in the list.
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


   // Set a click listener to play the audio when the list item is clicked on
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // Release the media player if it currently exists because we are about to
            // play a different sound file

          releaseMediaPlayer();

            // Get the {@link Word} object at the given position the user clicked on
            Word word = words.get(position);
            word.isPlaying = true;

            if(lastSelectedPosition != -1){
                Word lastWord = words.get(lastSelectedPosition);
                lastWord.isPlaying = false;

            }

            lastSelectedPosition = position;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            // Request audio focus so in order to play the audio file. The app needs to play a
            // short audio file, so we will request audio focus with a short amount of time
            // with AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT.
            int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener,
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);



            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                // We have audio focus now.

                      // Create and setup the {@link MediaPlayer} for the audio resource associated
                // with the current word
                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), word.getAudioResourceId());


                // Start the audio file
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                word.isPlaying = true;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


             // Setup a listener on the media player, so that we can stop and release the
                // media player once the sound has finished playing.
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);

            }



        }
    });

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    isActive = true;
 }

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    isActive = false;

     // When the activity is stopped, release the media player resources because we won't
    // be playing any more sounds.
    releaseMediaPlayer();

}

   /**
 * Clean up the media player by releasing its resources.
 */
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    // If the media player is not null, then it may be currently playing a sound.
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {

                    // Regardless of the current state of the media player, release its resources
        // because we no longer need it.
        mMediaPlayer.release();


                  // Set the media player back to null. For our code, we've decided that
        // setting the media player to null is an easy way to tell that the media player
        // is not configured to play an audio file at the moment.
        mMediaPlayer = null;

        // Regardless of whether or not we were granted audio focus, abandon it. This also
        // unregisters the AudioFocusChangeListener so we don't get anymore callbacks.
        mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
    }
}
}
```

and also in my Adapter i have an `if` `else` to turn the `boolean isPlaying` to `true` or `false` as below..

```
 if (currentWord.isPlaying == true){
        playIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        playIconPlaying.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else if (currentWord.isPlaying == false){
        playIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playIconPlaying.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

please suggest a suitable solution..

Comment: use `notifyDataSetChanged();` after your changes to widgets visibility.

Comment: @InsaneDeveloper used `notifyDataSetChanged();` in the adapter `if .. else` block, nothing seems to happen..

Comment: Why dont you use Observables and ViewModel! It's quite easy to handle runtime changes with no extra effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your Word class should have variable called isPlaying. It should not be in the fragment class.

```
class Word{
    boolean isPlaying;
    //other variables
}
class yourFragment{
  private int lastSelectedPosition = -1;



listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, 
                    int position, long l) {
            // Add the below lines to the existing code. Toggle play/pause
            Word word = words.get(position);
            word.isPlaying = true;

            if(lastSelectedPosition != -1){
                Word lastWord = words.get(lastSelectedPosition);
                lastWord.isPlaying = false;
            }

            lastSelectedPosition = position;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
}
```

}

change adapter getView as

```
 if (word.isPlaying == true){
        playIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        playIconPlaying.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (word.isPlaying == false){
        playIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playIconPlaying.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```